# Вызываются исключения в ASP .NET MVC при сборке проекта

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, asp

До определенного момента проект на .NET MVC собирался без ошибок. Стоило мне добавить метод в контроллер и собрать проект, как начали возникать такие сообщения: 
`Вызвано исключение: "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" в Microsoft.CSharp.dll
Вызвано исключение: "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" в Microsoft.CSharp.dll 
Вызвано исключение: "System.Web.HttpException" в System.Web.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException" в mscorlib.dll`
В результате чего HTML страница не отображается.

Пробовал закомментить практически весь код контроллера, убрать добавленный метод, но исключения остаются. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `У меня есть какой то код, но я вам его не покажу. Он падает с исключением, но текст исключения я не приведу. Я только скопирую строку, где написано, что исключение в принципе было`. Я верю, что у вас было исключение, но то, что вы привели, не говорит ни о чем.

Comment: к сожалению, я не знаю, из-за чего возникает исключение и не знаю, какой кусок кода лучше привести в примере

Comment: Добавил скриншот с вызванным исключением

Comment: @LevKostychenko Вы выложили текст и скриншот исключения, хотя от Вас просили код. Так Вам точно не помогут, т.к. экстрасенсов здесь нет. Правильно понял, что RunTime возникает после успешной сборки во время выполнения кода программы?

Comment: @LevKostychenko Если компиляция проходит успешно, то нужно поймать часть кода, где возникает исключение. Ставьте точку останова начиная со sturtup и шаг за шагом проверяйте работу программы.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev Я же написал, что не понимаю, о каком именно «коде» идёт речь. К тому же, весь код контроллера я пробовал закомментировать, что не привело ни к каким улучшениям, так что не вижу смысла показывать его код. И да, Runtime возникает после успешной сборки, но сама html страница не отображается.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev я пробовал отловить ту часть кода, где происходит ошибка, но даже первый метод контроллера не выполняется

Comment: @LevKostychenko Вы уверены, что дело в контроллере? Если даже первый метод контроллера не отлавливается, значит ошибка не в нём, а до него. Опять же, нет исходных данных, чтобы Вам можно было помочь с проблемой, а гадать - не выход.

Comment: @LevKostychenko Попробуйте для начала поднять точку останова в строку  21 . По идее, там еще не должно падать. У меня есть предположение, что db.PhotoSessions не соответствует типу модели, которую ожидает View. Проверьте этот момент. Тип db.PhotoSessions и (собака)model на View.